# Laravel exception daily reporting an error "View [pages.listing] not found."

Tags: php, laravel

So, our site has been up for a year and never really an issue but daily I receive a notification/log saying "View [pages.listing] not found." I view the site as soon as I receive this notification and everything seems to be fine (on my listing pages views). It's only about once a day.

```
   "class": "InvalidArgumentException",
   "message": "View [pages.listing] not found.",
   "code": 0,
   "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/frunkyea\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/View\/FileViewFinder.php:137",
   "trace": [...
```

I'm not sure how to fix whatever is causing our site to have these errors. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Search your project for `pages.listing`. Given that it's daily I'd suspect a cron is doing something that hits an old route or something along those lines.

Comment: That sounds annoying.  Try clearing view cache.  Maybe that file was there at some point and its being referenced.

Comment: Yes. I've cleared the view cache several times. Very odd.